# How to create tables in posgresql in helm

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed postgresql instance in k8s using helm and creating a database using values.yaml. Now How to create table.

```
global:
  postgresql:
    auth:
      # Added below credentials for testing
      postgresPassword: "postgresqladmin"
      username: "admin"
      password: "admin"
      database: "postgresqlDB"
containerPorts:
  postgresql: 5432
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: bitnami/postgresql
  tag: 15.4.0-debian-11-r10
  digest: ""
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  debug: false
```

Here is the command to install:

```
helm upgrade --install postgresql -f values.yaml bitnami/postgresql
```

And here is the command to access db(I am using suggested command after install)

```
kubectl run postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --image bitnami/postgresql --env="admin" --command -- psql --host postgresql -U admin -d postgresqlDB -p 5432
```

Comment: You can create a tunnel and access the db-server using psql.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Pasted from the console when installing postgresql: `kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/db-server 5432:5432 &
    PGPASSWORD="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" psql --host 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432`

Comment: I have updated question with command i use to connect to database

Comment: If you need help creating tables in postgresql you are better off looking at tutorials on this topic. This can get you started. https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/infrastructure/postgresql/administration/backup-restore-postgresql/

Comment: Also consider whether you can set up your application to run migrations, either at startup time or via a Helm hook, and use that approach to create tables (or modify or delete them).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**1. Access container**

You can access to your database after it has been mounted like this, and then execute your sql script.

kubectl run -it --rm --image=bitnami/postgresql:15.4.0-debian-11-r10 --restart=Never postgresql-client -- psql -h postgresql -U admin -d postgresqlDB

**2. Include a script to your deployment :**

You create an SQL script that create your table myscript.sql :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    field VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Create a ConfigMap, a YAML file (e.g., configmap-create-my-table.yaml) with the following content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: create-my-table-configmap
data:
  create_table.sql: |
    -- create_table.sql
    CREATE TABLE my_table (
       id serial PRIMARY KEY,
       field VARCHAR(255)
    );
```

Apply this to your cluster
 `kubectl apply -f configmap-create-table.yaml`

Adapt your helm chart :

```
postgresql:
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: create-my-table-configmap
      mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      readOnly: true
  extraVolumes:
    - name: create-my-table-configmap
      configMap:
        name: create-my-table-configmap
```

And then upgrade it :

`helm upgrade --install postgresql -f values.yaml bitnami/postgresql`

Comment: Thank you for an answer This looks very clear and easy to use, But i am not using config map at all  I have only the above commands to install. Is it necessary  to have config-map?

Comment: This is not the only option, you can also use Docker init by using a custom image like this : 
```
FROM postgres:15.4
# Copy your initialization scripts into the container
COPY init-scripts/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```
But I think you can also use initContainer in your Kubernetes Pod specification to perform initialization tasks before the main PostgreSQL container starts.

Comment: I think using docker wil be a good option for me. Do you have any example? or do you know if i can just run sql script file in ```kubectl run``` command?

Comment: You should mount volume /myscripts/ : /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Those scripts will be executed by Docker.

In a docker-compose it would look like this : 
```
volumes:
   - ./myScriptsFolder/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create table after you have created database using values.yaml, try these steps;

First you have to connect to postgreSQL using client:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --image=bitnami/postgresql:15.4.0-debian-11-r10 --namespace=YOUR_NAMESPACE postgresql-client -- bash
```

Now connect to your database inside the postgreSQL client pod;

```
psql -h postgresql -U admin -d postgresqlDB
```

NOw using simple SQL Commands, you can create tables;

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (255),
    age INT
);
```

After successfully creating the tables, you can exit the PostgreSQL client using;
ostgreSQL

```
\q
```

Hope it works:)

Answer (score 0):

once you start the database using -

```bash
kubectl run postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --image bitnami/postgresql -- bash
```

You'd need to connect to the instance via -

```bash
psql -h postgresql -U <your-username> -d <your-database>
```

You will be prompted for your password, which you specified in your values.yaml file (in your case, it's "postgresqladmin").

After this, you'll see the cursor change to postgresql / the username you specified, this indicates that you can now access the database using query language.

To create a table from here on, you can simply type in

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
    col1 serial PRIMARY KEY,
    col2 INT,
    col3 BOOLEAN
);
```

and it will create these columns with the specified data types and the primary key. You can exit the client using `\q` and exit the container futher using `exit`.

Comment: How to use my sql script file(create.sql) instead of typing script

Comment: for that, you need to copy the script file into your kube, using `kubectl cp create.sql postgresql-client:/create.sql` and then `psql -h postgresql -U <your-username> -d <your-database> -f /create.sql`

Comment: how to run these commands sequentially 
kubectl run postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --image bitnami/postgresql -- bash
kubectl cp ./create.sql postgresql-client:/create.sql 
psql -h postgresql -U <your-username> -d <your-database> -f /create.sql

Comment: cannot exec into a container in a completed pod; current phase is Failed. I get this error when i try to copy script file